# How we can write the test case which is not having any methods, only constant members in java?

Tags: java, junit5

How we can write the test case which is not having any methods, only constant members.

```java
public class DummyConstant {
    public static final String First_Name = "abc";
    public static final String Last_Name = "abc";
    public static final String Employer = "abc";
}
```

Comment: How can you test constant members? Can you give an example?

Comment: Does it return anything? If yes, you can write unit test to verify the same. Or if that method itself change/update structure of passed variable you can test it too.

Comment: This makes no sense to test constant variables. If you still want to do it, you can simply compare the value of the variable with the desired value.

Comment: You can assert that the constants have the values you think they ought to have, if you think that would be useful to you.

Comment: @hiteshbedre No It's not retuning anything.

Comment: If you test the values of constant members without any behavior (i.e. methods), you're just testing Java core functionality. I don't think that makes a lot of sense, but you could of course just assert that the value of a constant member equals that same value 

Comment: @aditya placing assert statement is the only way I guess here.

Comment: What's the point of writing a test to see if "X" equals "X"?  Your test will be at least as complicated as the code being tested, and therefore more likely to be wrong than the code is. "Code is what finds the bugs in your test cases".

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to test.

You either have these constants defined *and* use them, or you don't.  JUnit can't enforce whether or not you're using a variable, it can only enforce whether or not that value is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `assertj`, here is how to do it.

```
@Test
public void testingConstants() {
    assertThat(DummyConstant.First_Name).isEqualTo("abc");
    ...
}
```

I guess you can find a reason to do it: to avoid regression for example.

However, I'd advocate against this, as you're not testing any behaviour.
Those constants are / will probably (be) used in a functional unit somewhere, test it. Do not consider the testing of those constants important independently from their functional scope.